# Replace primary menu with secondary WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I want to display my secoundary menu with class from primary in navigation2.php.

function.php

```
function wpb_custom_new_menu() {
    register_nav_menu('secoundary',__( 'Secoundary' ));
  }
  add_action( 'init', 'wpb_custom_new_menu' );
```

header.php

```
<header id="page-header" <?php Medizin_Header::instance()->get_wrapper_class(); ?>>
    <div class="page-header-place-holder"></div>
    <div id="page-header-inner" class="page-header-inner" data-sticky="1">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="header-wrap">
                        <?php Medizin_THA::instance()->header_wrap_top(); ?>

                        <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/branding' ); ?>

                        <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/navigation' ); ?>

                        
        <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/navigation2' ); ?>
    </div>
    
</header>
```

navigation2.php

```
<div id="page-navigation" <?php Medizin::navigation_class(); ?>>
    <nav id="menu" class="menu menu--primary">
        <?php Medizin::menu_primary(); ?>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried to call your secondary menu? It doesn't appear that way.

Comment: i did it like this ```<?php
wp_nav_menu( array( 
    'theme_location' => 'my-custom-menu', 
    'container_class' => 'custom-menu-class' ) ); 
?>``` but i need class as well

Comment: Where is that on your code?

Comment: this code is working but without the classes and i dont know how to add class from primary menu

Comment: i need to find this ```Medizin::menu_primary();``` but i dont know where is it

Comment: ok, i found it :D in framework/class-static.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this like below code

```
<div id="page-navigation" <?php Medizin::navigation_class(); ?>>
    <nav id="menu" class="menu menu--primary">
        <?php Medizin::secoundary(); ?>
    </nav>
</div>
```